# More elegant/Pythonic way of printing elements of tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function which returns a large set of integer values as a tuple. For example:

```
def solution():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4 #etc.
```

I want to elegantly print the solution without the tuple representation. (i.e. parentheses around the numbers).

I tried the following two pieces of code.

```
print ' '.join(map(str, solution())) # prints 1 2 3 4
print ', '.join(map(str, solution())) # prints 1, 2, 3, 4
```

They both work but they look somewhat ugly and I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this. Is there a way to "unpack" tuple arguments and pass them to  the `print` statement in Python 2.7.5?

I would really love to do something like this:

```
print(*solution()) # this is not valid syntax in Python but I wish it was
```

kind of like tuple unpacking so that it's equivalent to:

```
print sol[0], sol[1], sol[2], sol[3] # etc.
```

Except without the ugly indexes. Is there any way to do that?

I know this is a stupid question because I'm just trying to get rid of parentheses but I was just wondering if there was something I was missing.

Comment: The `print` operator adds spaces between sequence elements by default so the first case could probably be achieved using: `print [x for x in solution()]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`print(*solution())` actually *can be* valid on python 2.7, just put:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

On the top of your file.

You could also iterate through the tuple:

```
for i in solution():
    print i,
```

This is equivalent to:

```
for i in solution():
    print(i, end= ' ')
```

If you ever use Python 3 or the import statement above.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
print str(solution()).strip('()')
```

Another possibility noted by [eyquem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551449/eyquem) in the comment:

```
print repr(solution())[1:-1]
```

Comment: Yes. I was just thinking to propose ``repr(solution())[1:-1]``